# In Drupal How can i get listed values from view in node creation?

Tags: listview, drupal-7, nodes

In drupal content creation 
How can i get listed values(District) from view in node creation after getting auto completion field(State)?

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite vague and without more information cannot be answered accurately as it really depends on how you store the state and district values.

However my suggestion would be to use taxonomy terms, with districts being a child term of a state.

Then use http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select to select the district in node creation.

Quick tip: you can use https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv to upload all districts into the taxonomy without manually doing it.